# Entropy of a single point (TV diagram)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

In my thermodynamics class, in a problem regarding a $TV$ diagram where the cycle is a closed rectangle (image at the end), I came across this question:

> Calculate the point along the path $d\to a$ where the gas has the same entropy as in point $b$, justifying accordingly.

Now, this was very confusing to me, because what I've learned is that, since entropy is a state function:

1. it can't be measured at a single point
2. in a closed cycle (such as this), $\Delta S_{gas}=0$

Could you please tell me if these suppositions are wrong? And if there is a point at which the entropy of the gas equals its entropy at $b$, how do I calculate either one?

[image: TV diagram]

Comment: Hint: they’re not asking you to actually calculate the entropy, just identify at what point between d and a where it’s the same as at b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, this was very confusing to me, because what I've learned is that,
>   since entropy is a state function:

That is correct. Entropy is a system property.

> it can't be measured at a single point

While it is not usually given specific values at a given point (one exception is in the steam tables for water), you do not need to calculated a specific value of entropy to solve this problem so the supposition is irrelevant.

> in a closed cycle (such as this), Δ=0

That is correct. Start at any point and if you return to that point $\Delta S=0$.

> Could you please tell me if these suppositions are wrong? And if there
>   is a point at which the entropy of the gas equals its entropy at ,
>   how do I calculate either one?

Supposition 1 is not needed for solve the problem. Supposition 2 is correct. But you don't the need to "calculate" the entropy at $b$ to solve your problem. You need to understand what the processes are and how they affect entropy change. We don't solve homework and exercise problems on this site, but as guidance I suggest you ask yourself the following:

1. What type of process does each segment of the path (d-a, a-b, b-c, c-d) describe.
2. Which processes involve heat into the system and which involve heat out and how does that effect entropy change?
3. At which of the four points (a,b,c, or d) in the cycle is the entropy a maximum? A minimum?
4. What does that tell you about the entropy of the remaining two points?

Hope this helps.